# Wish to share the same document between two seperate document libraries

Tags: content-type, libraries

Our Sharepoint setup at work requires a document being created in one library (FBD) using a set of generic content types, and these same content types having been setup are being used in a different library (PFB) but allowing the FBD library to show this document that was created in the PFB library with minimal manual intervention.

Comment: So Basically you want to copy document from Document library (FBD) to Document Library(PFB). Right ?   If Yes , Than i want to know are you using share point online or share point on prem ?

Answer (score 1):

Expecting that you don't want to have two copies of the same document, I would suggest taking a look at the content query webpart. You can combine information from multiple lists/libraries into one view.